# How do i make a bot wait for a picture?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried everything but i don't find a working code for my discord.py bot to ask for a picture, wait for the user to send it, and then reply. I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) for a message with an attachment, you can do it in a check func

```py
@bot.command()
async def wait_for_attachment(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and bool(message.attachments)

    await ctx.send('Waiting for an attachment')
    resp = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    
    image = resp.attachments[0]

    await ctx.send('replying')
```

Note: This waits for all types of files, `json`, `py`, `jpg`, `png`... If you want only specific types of files you can do it with `message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('extension_here')`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about discord.py but are there not events for pictures sent by users? If so what about replying when the event is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

To do so you need to use `wait_for` ([Document here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for))
You can use `check` to check if the message has an image

```py
async def request_image(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Send the image')

    def check(message):
        attachments = message.attachments
        if len(attachments) == 0:
            return False
        attachment = attachments[0]
        return attachment.filename.endswith(('.jpg', '.png'))

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    image = msg.attachments[0]
```